# UILabel background Color NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

I've made a RGB slider and I want to save the slider value and background color of two labels to NSUserDefaults. Saving the sliderValue works fine, but for the label background color my code doesn't work. Have I written my code correctly?

Information: the background color from label1 should be saved in NSUserDefaults.

This line

```
NSString* label1 = self.label1.backgroundColor;
```

Is producing this error

> incompatible pointer types intializing NSString with an expression of type UIColor

And this line

```
[defaults setObject:label1 forKey:@"label1"];
```

Is producing this error

> local declaration of ´label1´hides instance variable

Here is my .m file:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

self.label1.backgroundColor =[defaults objectForKey:@"label1"];
self.labelRot.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"labelRot"];
self.labelBlau.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"labelBlau"];
self.labelGruen.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"labelGruen"];

self.sliderRot.value = [defaults floatForKey:@"sliderRot"];
self.sliderBlau.value = [defaults floatForKey:@"sliderBlau"];
self.sliderGruenn.value = [defaults floatForKey:@"sliderGruenn"];


//labelRot.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderRot.value];
//labelGruen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderGruenn.value];
//labelBlau.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderBlau.value];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (IBAction)red:(id)sender {

if (sender == _sliderRot) {
    _labelRot.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderRot.value];
    [self farbeWechseln];
}

}- (IBAction)green:(id)sender {

if (sender == _sliderGruenn) {
    _labelGruen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderGruenn.value];
    [self farbeWechseln];
}

- (IBAction)blue:(id)sender {

if (sender == _sliderBlau) {
    _labelBlau.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", _sliderBlau.value];
    [self farbeWechseln];
}


- (IBAction)farbe:(id)sender {

[self farbeWechseln];



- (void)farbeWechseln {

    [label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:_sliderRot.value/255 green:_sliderGruenn.value/255 blue:_sliderBlau.value/255 alpha:1.0]];
    [label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:_sliderRot.value/255 green:_sliderGruenn.value/255 blue:_sliderBlau.value/255 alpha:1.0]];
}

- (void)speichernDefaults {

// hier werden die UserDefaults gespeichert

NSString* label1 = self.label1.backgroundColor; //HERE IS MY FIRST ERROR = incompatible pointer types intializing NSString with an expression of type UIColor
NSString *labelRot = self.labelRot.text;
NSString *labelBlau = self.labelBlau.text;
NSString *labelGruen = self.labelGruen.text;



float sliderRot = self.sliderRot.value;
float sliderGruenn = self.sliderGruenn.value;
float sliderBlau = self.sliderRot.value;


NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:label1 forKey:@"label1"]; //HERE IS MY SECOND ERROR = local declaration of ´label1´hides instance variable

[defaults setObject:labelRot forKey:@"labelRot"];
[defaults setObject:labelBlau forKey:@"labelBlau"];
[defaults setObject:labelGruen forKey:@"labelGruen"];


[defaults setFloat:sliderRot forKey:@"sliderRot"];
[defaults setFloat:sliderGruenn forKey:@"sliderGruenn"];
[defaults setFloat:sliderBlau forKey:@"sliderBlau"];

// dieser Befehl ist für sofortiges Speichern der Userdefaults
    [defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your first problem:

```
NSString* label1 = self.label1.backgroundColor;
```

You're attempting to make a variable of type NSString and assign a UIColor object to it. You need to make sure that your variable is the same type as the object that you're trying to assign to it. It should be:

```
UIColor *label1Color = self.label1.backgroundColor;
```

Notice that I didn't just change the type of the variable, but its name as well. This is important for a couple of reasons. Generally, you want to name your variables in a way that makes that they store clear to you when you read them, and `label1` as a variable name sounds like a label, not a color.

Which leads me to your second error. The problem here is that you've given your color variable the same name as your label, and since you have two variables called `label1` visible at this scope, the compiler complains. Changing your variable name as I've done in the code above will resolve this issue as well, but there's still one more problem with your code.

You can't save a UIColor object directly to NSUserDefaults. You need to convert the color into one of the data types that can be stored there, like NSData, which can be done like this:

```
NSData *dataFromLabel1Color = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:label1Color];
[defaults setObject:dataFromLabel1Color forKey:@"label1Color"];
```

You will also have to modify how you get the color back out of NSUserDefaults to transform the value back to UIColor from NSData. This can be achieved with the following:

```
UIColor *label1Color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"label1Color"]];
self.label1.backgroundColor = label1Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UIColor` can't be saved directly to `NSUserDefaults`.  Erica Sadun has a great writeup on creating a `UIColor` category to allow easy saving.  I'd recommend converting the color to a hex string to save and the converting the hex strubg back to a color to apply as background color.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components/

Answer (score 0):

Property list files can only store basic data types and cannot contain custom objects. You need to convert your object to an NSData object if you want it to be written to the plist. You can do this with NSKeyedArchiver, which will encode an object which conforms to the NSCoding protocol into an NSData object.

please read this block to have better understanding of plist..
[Link](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/property-list-seralization/)

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1 : you already have a global property: UILabel *label1 and you create another local property NSString *label1 --> rename your properties

ERROR 2: same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can save it by converting the float values to a UIColor and then to a hexcode which is ultimately a string and you can store string values in NSUserDefaults.
Code for Conversion from UIColor to String(hexcode) and vice versa

```
-(NSString*)getHexcode::(UIColor *)mycolor {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(mycolor.CGColor);
    CGFloat r = components[0];
    CGFloat g = components[1];
    CGFloat b = components[2];

    NSString *colorHexCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02lX%02lX%02lX", (long)(r * 255.0), (long)(g * 255.0), (long)(b * 255.0)];

    return colorHexCode;
}
```

Then you can use this function to get a UIColor for your label by passing the hexcode which is the string value from your NSUserdefaults

```
-(UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;

    if([hexString isEqual:@""])
    {
        hexString=defaultGreenColor;
    }

    if([hexString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        hexString=defaultGreenColor;
    }

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Hope it helps